# Prime number calculation in Pascal

Tags: delphi, freepascal, pascalscript

I have a code here which tells you if a number is prime or not in Pascal but it keeps on displaying this error that I am missing a parentheses on line 20 yet I don't think any more parentheses is needed. This is the error:

```
Compiling pascal.pas
pascal.pas(20,13) Fatal: Syntax error, ")" expected but "ordinal const" found
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppc386 returned an error exitcode
```

This is my code:

```
program PrimeNumbers;

var 
input: integer;
finalResult: integer;

function checkPrime(numb :integer): integer;
var
    result, i: integer;

    
begin
    if(numb = 1)then
        result := 1;
    
    i:= 2;
    
    while i < numb do
        begin
            if(numb % i = 0)then
                result:= 1;
        
            i =: i +1; 
        end
    result:= 0;
end

begin
    writeln('Giev me a number and I will tell u if its a prime or not');
    readln(input);
    finalResult:= checkPrime(input);
    
    if(finalResult = 1)then
        writeln('Your number is not a prime');
    else
        writeln('Your number is a prime number');
end.
```

Comment: Actually, it's not a dupe - thought this was operator precedence, but modulo in Delphi/Pascal is `mod`, not `%`.  You want `if(numb mod i = 0)`. Would close this as a typo, tbh.  Might as well read the dupe anyway - you'll hit that roadbump eventually.

Comment: `i =: i +1;` isn't going to work either.